# Upgrading my 32 bit Windows 10 Desktop RAM from 2 GB to 6 GB i.e 2+4. Is it less efficient in any way than 8 GB RAM i.e 2+6

Tags: windows, memory

I've heard somewhere that the RAM should be in powers of 2 in order to be more efficient, i.e. For example 2GB, 4GB, 8GB, 16GB and so on. So can I upgrade my 2GB RAM with an additional 4GB RAM to use a total of 6GB RAM.

Comment: \*cough\* 32bit \*cough\* 4GB max \*cough\*

Comment: I didn't think there were any 32-bit editions of Win 10.

Comment: Oh, there are apparently. How 20th Century!

Answer (score 0):

*"When different sizes are installed you operate in SINGLE CHANNEL mode, and when installed in identical PAIRS you operate in DUAL CHANNEL mode.*

*The CPU can communicate up to 2x faster in Dual Channel.*

*Real-world performance varies though as the CPU and Memory don't talk constantly. You might bottleneck by between 10% and 40% by being in Single instead of Dual. It depends on how fast your CPU, how fast your RAM is, and what program you're using.*

*To prevent bottlenecking you may wish to get an identical 4GB module to replace the 2GB one."*

---

*Source from: **http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1892163/whats-problem-6gb-ram.html***

---

Edit: Also 32bit computers only have a 4GB ram limit. Anything above that will not be recognised on Windows or any other operating system. I recommend you upgrade your Windows OS to 64bit if you are thinking of a ram upgrade.